# Django change url programmatically

Tags: python, django, urlconf

I have to page in my django powered website. `index.html` and `books.html`

I have this link to the `books.html` in my first page

```
<a href="books.html">books</a>
```

and this one is in `books.html` for getting back to the first page.

```
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
```

and my url conf is like this

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^books.html/$', 'mysite.views.bookpage', name='books'),
    url(r'index.html/$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
)
```

and `views.py`

```
def home(request):
        return render_to_response('index.html')

def bookpage(request):
        return render_to_response('books.html')
```

When I click on the second link to get back home. my url address looks like this

```
mysite.com/books.html/index.html/
```

How can I change url back to `mysite.com/` when clicking on the second link in `books.html`?

*sorry if the title is not appropriate. i didn't know what would be my question title*

**Update**

I've deleted `url(r'^index.html/$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home')` from my url patterns and used `<a href="{% url 'home' %}">` in the second page. But nothing happens when I click on that link

Comment: Is the view referenced in the sample `mysite.views`? or `azahra.views`?

Comment: @Brandon Sorry. its mysite. my bad.

Comment: Help me understand why you want/need `index.html` to point to the home view instead of `/`

Comment: @Brandon because `/` doesn't work when I use it in `href`

Comment: I think there's something larger at fault if `/` isn't working to get you back to the site root. That should work no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. With Django don't write `<a href="anything.html">`. You should use `url` template tag for page addresses. More on `url` template tag here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Example: `<a href="{% url 'home' %}">`

2. In your urls.py you have `^books.html/$` and `index.html/$`. Notice the missing `^` before index? You may want to add it.
3. Don't use same name for different patterns in urls.py.

Comment: But nothing happens when I use `<a href="{% url 'home' %}">`

Comment: That's most likely because there are two patterns named "home"

Comment: But it is in my urlconf. isn't it?

Comment: The problem is somewhere in my `js` codes. it works when I try it in a test `<a>` tag. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Two issues that have been missed in the other answers:

1. You're missing a `^` in your third URL: `url(r'^index.html/$', 'azahra.views.home', name='home'),`
2. You have two URLs with the same `name='home'`. One of them should be changed.

As mentioned, you should also be using `{% url 'url_name' %}` [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#url), instead of hard-coding in your templates.

Also, unless your application is actually named `mysite`, you need to change that to reference your actual views...

Comment: I've deleted `url(r'^index.html/$', 'azahra.views.home', name='home'),` from my url patterns and used `<a href="{% url 'home' %}">` in the second page. But nothin happens

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happens"? Do you get an error?

Comment: No. there is no errors. its like you don't click at all!

Comment: Do you actually have an app called `mysite`?

Comment: The problem is somewhere in my `js` codes. it works when I try it in a test `<a>` tag. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `^`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^books.html/$', 'azahra.views.bookpage', name='books'),
    url(r'^index.html/$', 'azahra.views.home', name='home'),
)
```

Take a look at the [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag - it'll simplify your URL routing in your templates and move you away from these types of errors.

Comment: That throws` Page not found (404)`